# use function like application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

before in application , i used a function . i add it to my sqlserver --> database --> Programmabality ---> Function ---> Scalered-Value Function

and in the application i used , like this :

```
         dbo.MyFunc(_txt.text);
```

but now i need this function in my project . its mvc4 web site .
is it possible to use like that ? and where i should add this function?
of course i did like application , but db.MyFunc() dose not recognize in my class.

so,my project is CodeFirst .

Answer (score 0):

As you are using code first DB approach, code changes will be reflected in SQL server DB. So you'll have to implement it in C#
Below is one example. Got from [How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    public const double SALES_TAX = .086;

    [SqlFunction()]
    public static SqlDouble addTax(SqlDouble originalAmount)
    {
        SqlDouble taxAmount = originalAmount * SALES_TAX;

        return originalAmount + taxAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: however, if you don't want to implement this in C#(or say VB), then code first will not help you much here...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want direct access to this specific function:

```
public Object MyFunc(String txt_text)
{
    Object result = null;

    String connectionstring = "DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;"
                            + "Initial Catalog=DEMO;"
                            + "Integrated Security=True"; // or whatever you use....
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Myfunc(@p1)", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txt_text);
            result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

That would establish a connection to the database and execute that scalar-values function, then place the result within `result`. This takes any other database infrastructure out of the equation and just allows you to directly call your SQL function.

Comment: hello Brad Christie. my connection string is not like usual .it's like this : public SportContext()
  :base(SharedDll.Connections.ConnectionString()) . how can i use it in my connection string like something you wrote.

Comment: Instead of a hard coded steering use the direct reference to your connection string method.

Comment: Also,  is sportcontext an instance of DbContext?